# Is it idiomatic to say in detail with information?

Tags: idiomatic-language

**I want his information in detail**

Doesn't information itself mean details?

I wonder if it's idiomatic or not?

Answer (score 1):

Information can be partial or complete, detailed or brief/not detailed/general etc. To specify 'in detail' is to emphasise that the maximum amount of information possible is desired. If you asked me to tell you about my father, I could give you brief information about him - his name, year of birth and occupation, perhaps. I could give you more detailed information - his full name, dates of birth and death, height, education, military service, hobbies, tastes in literature and music, favourite pets, shoe size, medical history, religious affiliation, in fact I could go on until you told me to stop.

> in detail ​
>
> including or considering all the information about
>   something or every part of something:

[In detail](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/detail)

Answer (score 0):

It is idiomatic. information doesn't mean details. it means instructions about something and it can be general or detailed.